# Problem reconnecting SMTP on one TIdSMTP instance

Tags: exception, smtp, indy10, delphi-10-seattle

I use `TIdSMTP` to send emails. There have been no problems with any server up until now, however, we recently encountered a server where on the second iteration of establishing a connection I get an `EIdConnClosedGracefully` exception.

Of course, we can also send many messages on one connection and it works correctly, but unfortunately we also have to maintain a mechanism in this system where a new connection is established for each message, so we send the message and close the connection.

This all takes place on one `TIdSMTP` instance, and that's where we get an exception.

I have already checked and if I create a new `TIdSMTP` instance for each message, everything works fine.

Has anyone encountered such a problem before? Is a code necessary?

There is my code:

```
fIdSMTP:=TIdSMTP.Create;
fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
fIdSMTP.IOHandler:=fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

...
{ configuration }
...

procedure TMainMailSender.SendMessage(var 
  pSendingResult:Boolean);
var
  Sent: Boolean;
begin
  pSendingResult:=False;
  Sent:=False;
  try
    try
      if IsConnectionForEachMessage then
        begin
          if (not fIdSMTP.Connected) then
            fIdSMTP.Connect;
        end;
      try
        if fIdSMTP.Connected then
          begin
            fIdSMTP.Send(fIdMessage);
            Sent:=True;
          end;
      finally
        if IsConnectionForEachMessage then
          begin
            if fIdSMTP.Connected then
              fIdSMTP.Disconnect;
            if (fIdSMTP.IOHandler <> Nil) then
              begin
                fIdSMTP.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
                fIdSMTP.IOHandler.Close;
              end;
          end;
      end;
    except
      on E:Exception do
        begin
          fErrorMessage:=E.Message;
          fIdSMTP.Disconnect(False);
          if (fIdSMTP.IOHandler <> Nil) then
            fIdSMTP.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
        end;
    end;
  finally
    pSendingResult:=Sent;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you clearing the `TIdSMTP.IOHandler` of unread data between reconnects? If not, try that. I'm not aware of any other issues with reconnecting, so you may need to show your actual code, and it would also be useful if you could include the call stack leading up to the exception.

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you for your help. I added a method above that iterates over one message.

Comment: This code has worked fine so far with many different smtp accounts. Now I have a configuration that doesn't want to work.

Comment: You don't need to call `IOHandler.Close;` at all, let Indy handle that internally. And you don't need so many `Connected` checks, either, 1 check should suffice. Simply `if not Connected then Connect`, then `Send`, then `Disconnect`+`Clear` if needed. Done.